# Cross sub-domain ajax form submit with session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on something here.

**Javascript**

```
  $('#create').submit(function() {
$.ajax({ 
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: $(this).attr('method'), 
    url: $(this).attr('action'), 
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

Php file (url):

```
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_set_cookie_params( time() + 3600, '/', '.domain.com');
print_r($_SESSION);
die;
```

On the page with the form my session[memberid] = [some int];

But if i make the ajax call the whole sesison variable is empty

I tried looking on google for some answers, i tried looking for some answers on stack overflow

but nothing really helped. And i do not prefer using an iframe. Maybe that was the solution, but maybe there is someone who knows what i need to do here.

The form is located at the domain m.domain.com
and the php file is located at domain.com

Comment: Can you post the raw ajax request/response including headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I fixed it. I copied my file from the root to my mobile root directory and then include via the real root. It works now. I tried the other comments but those won't work either.

Thanks all for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

Also you have to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');` to the server side to properly handle the call.

Read [more here](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/) about CORS and server side handling

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell jQuery to use the CORS client-side support in XHR2:

```
$('#create').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'), 
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Then you've not configured your server-side support correctly, or the version of the browser you're using doesn't support XHR2.

Comment: but if i set my session on domain.com and i go to m.domain.com everything works fine, but when I do the ajax call I don't get the session. So my cookies are cross sub-domain